# Add extra values to databound DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

### Background

I have a datagridview that is bound to a dataset. That dataset stores data from a sql db that is obtained using a SqlCommandBuilder. When the dataset is updated the db is updated too.

This works fine.

However I would like one of the columns to contain a combobox.
To do this I have added a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn and hidden the original column. I've then then tried to add extra items to the combobox and then bound the dataset.

### My Code

```
 dataGridView1.DataSource = JoblistDataSet.Tables["Joblist"]; //bind ds to dgv
            dataGridView1.Columns["Status"].Visible = false; //hide original column


            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Status = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

            //setup combobox
            Status.Items.Insert(0, "Select Status");//add extra items
            Status.DataSource = JoblistDataSet.Tables["Joblist"];//add original item from ds
            Status.HeaderText = @"Status   ";
            Status.DisplayMember = "Status";
            Status.DropDownWidth = 78;
            Status.DataPropertyName = "Status";
            Status.DisplayIndex = 7;

            //add combobox
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Status);

            dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

### What i'm Trying to Achieve

I would like a combobox on one of the datagridview columns. In that combobox, the first item should contain (and be displayed) the row's actual value, the other items should contain the other available items.

### Question

However, this doesn't seem to work. All I'm getting is the actual rows actual value. Am i going the wrong way about it. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You need to assign a `ValueMember` to the combo box so that the underlying data can bind to the correct property of the items in the combo. The reason I don't post an answer is because I don't understand if you are intentionally binding the combobox to the same data source as the grid or if you are doing it in error. It makes no sense to bind the same data table to both the grid and the combobox.

Comment: @Crowcoder I'm probably doing it in error. Read a few tutorials and that's what a few did to get the current row value for that column to appear in the combobox.

Comment: maybe [one of my blog posts](http://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/14/a-basic-example-of-crud-with-datagridview-in-vb-net/) can help. Its a VB.net example but still applicable to c#.